# TigerVNC fullscreen is stretched and split across both screens on KDE 20.04. How do i get it on just one screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde, vnc, fullscreen, plasma-5

TigerVNC fullscreen is stretched and split across both screens on kubuntu 20.04.

Looking thru all the "system settings" i don't see anything relevant.

Not a problem on lubuntu 20.04.

How do i get TigerVNC fullscreen on just one screen in KDE?

Answer (score 0):

Im am on Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome but I had the same issue.

TigerVNC spreads the full-screen over all monitors by default.

You can change the seting inside TigerVNC viewer: press the menu key (F8) and go to 'Options...'

In 'Screen': uncheck 'Enable full-screen mode over all monitors'